# Install printer aficio gx e3300n

Tags: drivers, printing, hardware

I searched for printer drivers for Ubuntu and did not find them anywhere.

Is there some form of “emulation” for the original driver for Windows?

Comment: No, you can't emulate Windows drivers.

Comment: http://forums.openprinting.org/read.php?30,14344